# How do i move an item in a matrix using just user inputs?

Tags: python

im really new to python programming. Currently im trying to make a simple maze game using nested list and user inputs. But i cant really grasp the algorithm for how should i move one specific element in a nested list in any direction(left,right,up,down) so basically i need to change coordinates each step at the time?
So lets say i need to move item P around in list below, and the only path is through zeros. Xs are the walls.

```
Maze = [ 
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
['X', 'P', 'O', 'X', 'X'],
['X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
['X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
['X', '0', '0', '0', 'X'],
['X', 'O', 'X', 'T', 'X'],
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
]     
 for line in maze:
print(' '.join(line))

user = input('Move')
posx = maze[1]
posy = maze[1]

if user == 'a':
    posx -= 1
elif user == 'd':
    posx += 1
elif user == 'w':
    posy += 1
elif user == 's':
    posy -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do *not* move the item through the matrix.  Your player doesn't *replace* the location contents; she shares the location temporarily.

Keep a master copy of the maze; keep a 2-element list with the player's coordinates.  The *only* time you care about displaying the player is when you print the maze state.  Put this into a function; inside that function, insert the player into the output.  For instance:

```
maze_view = copy.deepcopy(maze)
maze_view[player_pos[0]][player_pos[1]] = 'P'
# print the maze as normal.
```

Answer (score 0):

Very fun game! I agree with @prune with the master copy of the maze, but I did it as a swapping for now. Lists don't have built-in convenient ways to swap values around, especially between nested lists, so you'll have to do it manually.

```
def move(maze, posx, posy, dx, dy):
    new_x = posx + dx
    new_y = posy + dy
    val_to_swap = maze[new_y][new_x]
    # Check for legal move?
    maze[new_y][new_x] = "P"
    maze[posy][posx] = "0"
    return new_x, new_y


def print_maze(maze):
    for line in maze:
        print(line)


Maze = [
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
['X', 'P', 'O', 'X', 'X'],
['X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
['X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'],
['X', '0', '0', '0', 'X'],
['X', 'O', 'X', 'T', 'X'],
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
]
print_maze(Maze)

posx = 1
posy = 1
game_not_won=True

while(game_not_won):
    dx = 0
    dy = 0
    user = input('Move')
    if user == 'a':
        dx = -1
    elif user == 'd':
        dx = 1
    elif user == 'w':
        dy = -1
    elif user == 's':
        dy = 1
    posx, posy = move(Maze, posx, posy, dx, dy)
    print_maze(Maze)
    # Check for winning?
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think im starting undersand the algorithm behind this simple task. Even thou im still struggling to stop P move into X(to make X work as a wall). This is actually  supposed to be a base of an simple maze game(different maze grid thou). If anyone has an idea or suggestions to how i could solve that P doesn’t move into X, I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Good luck with your game : ) The general idea of what you are trying to do is check that your player has "made a legal move". I did put a comment in the code as to a potential place to start. You'll need to figure out how the program should react to an illegal move (end the game, not move, erase hard drive, become sentient, etc.) and what visual feedback to give to the user.